# Trying to output all possible combinations of two files

Tags: file, compare

Hello I am trying to make a perl script that will take 2 files (that contain words) and joins them for every possible combination.

eg.

file 1 containing:

```
  make 
  move
```

file 2 containing:

```
   on
   out
```

output file should read:

```
   makeon
   makeout
   moveon
   moveout
```

Ideally it'd be nice to have the orders of the file reversed I.E

onmove
   outmove
   onmake
   outmake

Below are a few things i've tried but I'm a beginner and can never get the output right

```
! /usr/bin/perl



open (OUT, '> output.txt');

use strict;

use warnings;

use Data::Dump qw(dump);

my @in = qw(aaa bbb ccc ddd);

my @list;

while(my $first = shift @in) {

        last unless @in;
        my $rest = join'\n', @in;
        push @list, glob("{$first}{$rest}");
}
        dump @list;




# Some other attempts


my @karray;

my @sarray;

my @testarr = (@sarray)+@karray;

my $stemplate = "test1.txt";

my $ktemplate = "test2.txt";

my $outtemplate = "output.txt";

sub pushf2a {

  open(IN, "<$_[0]") || die;

  while (<IN>) {

    if ($_[0] eq $stemplate) {

      push (@sarray,@karray,$_);

    } else {

      push (@karray,@sarray,$_);
    }

  }

  close(IN) || die  $!;

}

&pushf2a($stemplate, @sarray);

&pushf2a($ktemplate, @karray);

print OUT @sarray, @karray;

print OUT @list;

close (OUT);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably slicker ways to do it, but this is straightforward:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use Tie::File;
use strict;
use warnings;

tie my @a, 'Tie::File', $ARGV[0] or die "$ARGV[0]: $!\n";
tie my @b, 'Tie::File', $ARGV[1] or die "$ARGV[1]: $!\n";
foreach my $w( @b ) { print "$w$_\n" foreach( @a )}
```

Invoke this script with your two input files as arguments.  For example, if you put the above in the file named "combine" and make it executable:

```
./combine file1.txt file2.txt
```